# Регулярное выражение (числа разделенные знаком ;)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выражение:

```
#.*;$dep;.*$dep2;.*#
```

Оно обрабатывает сроку вида ;100;60;18;22;159;

Мне нужно, чтобы это выражение проверяло есть ли в данной строке цифры $dep и $dep2 ограниченные знаком ;. Но в данный момент оно будет срабатывать даже если $dep2 является просто последней цифрой какого-либо числа.

Вопрос: как мне указать, что перед числом может не стоять знак ; только если это число следует за числом $dep, а во всех остальных случаях он обязателен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ведь используете PHP? В таком случае можно использовать [positive lookbehind](http://de.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), позволяющий удостовериться, что перед паттерном стоит заданный символ. Например, так:

```
#.*;$dep;.*(?<=;)$dep2;.*#
```